# How to send OffsetCommitRequest for a consumer in Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, offset, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to use the OffsetCommitRequest in Kafka consumer API for version 0.9 which is included in the following package:
org.apache.kafka.common.requests.OffsetCommitRequest

How to send this request? What is the ideal way to use this?
I want to commit the offsets in Kafka itself. I did not find any documentation related to version 0.9. Most of it is available for 0.8.x

Also, the constructor for this request takes generation id, member id and retention time. What are these fields?

Comment: Go through this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka

Comment: I already did. It's for the older version. It uses a BlockingChannel to send the request which is not available in 0.9

Comment: Kafka documentation for version 0.9 are available here: http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html

Comment: Abhay, I have gone through this doc too. Didn't get my answer. Can you please point to the section where my question is answered exactly?

Comment: If you want to commit offsets, just use the new high level consumer and call `consumer.commit()`. http://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0.9-consumer-client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to commit offset manually, maybe you should set consumer property

`enable.auto.commit=false`

and use commitSync() or commitAsync() method of kafka consumer.
For example you can call commitSync() after all ConsumerRecords were processed.
Or you can commit only for TopicPartition that you want even after each received ConsumerRecord. Like this:

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsetMap = new HashMap<>();
offsetMap.put(new TopicPartition(someTopic, somePartition), new OffsetAndMetadata(someOffset));
kafkaConsumer.commitSync(offsetMap);
```

Comment: That's the final solution that I have resorted to. Thanks anyways :)
But I would still like to have an answer to my original question. I think this request object can be very handy at times.